# How to find out the specs of a stereoscopic lens attached to a smart phone?

Tags: iphone, image-processing, stereo-3d, stereoscopy

I bought a cheap snap on stereoscopic lens from here:

http://www.aliexpress.com/item/New-3d-Lens-for-Iphone-6-6s-Plus-5-5s-Samsung-Galaxy-S5-S6-Edge-Note/32526390597.html?ws_ab_test=searchweb201556_2,searchweb201644_0,searchweb201560_4

I am trying to do some depth measurement. But to do that I need to know the separation and also the angle the mirror is placed. I don't think the manufacturer will provide the numbers. How else can I find out? Is there any grid test I can do to accurately get the constant number?

KP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you need to do  *calibration* of your cameras.

See here for a nice read-up:
http://www.jayrambhia.com/blog/stereo-calibration/

Comment: Oh gosh thanks Rob that is like the one line answer I was seeking. Thanks! I did something for single camera but forgot the same can be done for stereo.